# Dispatch action every X second using Redux Saga

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

Being completely new to redux-saga, I am trying to set up a saga which reacts on action `LANGUAGE_START_CYCLE` and cycles the action `LANGUAGE_CYCLE` every 3 second.

But the saga `LANGUAGE_CYCLE` is never run as I would expect when I dispatch `LANGUAGE_START_CYCLE` to the Redux store.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I would suspect it being a simple mistake as my other sagas are running just fine.

```
// constants/ActionTypes.js
export const LANGUAGE_SET_ACTIVE = "LANGUAGE_SET_ACTIVE";
export const LANGUAGE_START_CYCLE = "LANGUAGE_START_CYCLE";
export const LANGUAGE_STOP_CYCLE = "LANGUAGE_STOP_CYCLE";
export const LANGUAGE_CYCLE = "LANGUAGE_CYCLE";


// actions/language.js
export const cycleLanguage = () => {
    return {
        type: ActionTypes.LANGUAGE_CYCLE
    }
};    

// languageSaga.js
import { actionChannel, call, take, put, race } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import * as ActionTypes from '../constants/ActionTypes';
import * as actions from '../actions/language';

const wait = ms => {
    new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms)
    })
};

export default function * languageSaga() {
    const channel = yield actionChannel(ActionTypes.LANGUAGE_START_CYCLE);
    while (yield take(channel)) {
        while (true) {
            const { stopped } = yield race({
                wait: call(wait, 3000),
                stopped: take(ActionTypes.LANGUAGE_STOP_CYCLE)
            });

            if (!stopped) {
                yield put(actions.cycleLanguage());
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}


// sagas.js (root sagas)
export default function * sagas() {
    yield [
        directorySaga(), // Another saga which works fine
        pusherSaga(), // Another saga which works fine
        languageSaga()
    ]
}
```

Example of one of my other sagas, which are working:

```
// directorySaga.js
function * fetchDirectory(action) {
    try {
        const directory = yield call(Api.fetchDirectory, action.id);
        yield put(fetchDirectorySucceeded(directory));
    } catch (e) {
        yield put(fetchDirectoryFailed(e.message));
    }
}

export default function * directorySaga() {
    yield * takeLatest(ActionTypes.DIRECTORY_REQUESTED, fetchDirectory);
}
```

Comment: Sorry but you don't really tell what's going wrong here so it's hard to help you. What do you dispatch, what do you expect, what do you obtain?

Comment: The problem is that when i dispatch `LANGUAGE_START_CYCLE`, the saga does not run my race effect. I've tried to try/catch everywhere, but no output whatsoever. Any hints on how to troubleshoot this better?

Comment: Put logs and tell which gets printed or not. I don't even know if you are going into the loops there :)

Comment: Wauw, just made some observations. Going to answer the question myself, you be surprised (maybe) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to answer my question here.

The above code i working, but when I was triggering the actions, I was using [Redux Dev Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd) to dispatch actions to the store.

I manually dispatched `LANGUAGE_START_CYCLE` using the tools, which changed the state - but apparently this did not notify the saga middle-ware and my channel was never updated:

[image: Redux Dev Tools dispatching]

But when using a simple button in one of my components:

```
<button onClick={() => dispatch(actions.startCycle())}>
    Start
</button>
<button onClick={() => dispatch(actions.stopCycle())}>
    Stop
</button>
```

The saga middle-ware was notified.

**UPDATE**

My store configuration is:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import rootReducer from '../reducers/index';
import sagas from '../sagas/index';

export default function configureStore(initialState) {
  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware),
    window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f
  ));

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept('../reducers', () => {
      const nextReducer = require('../reducers');
      store.replaceReducer(nextReducer);
    });
  }

  sagaMiddleware.run(sagas);

  return store;
}
```

Comment: Can I see how you create your store? This may be because of using wrong middleware ordering

Comment: you should try to always declare the saga middleware last. It will be applied first in fact (application list is reversed). In your case the store you pass to devtools is not yet enhanced by saga, meaning that dispatching from devtools is the raw dipatch of Redux without any middleware

Comment: you should register middlewares in the order you want the middleware to process. Begin by thunk/async/promise/..., middle devtools, last saga.

Comment: If I do `const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
      window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f,
      applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
  ));` the sagas are not working?

Comment: I used this guide for integration: https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/blob/0757dac4c2eb217d7bbb8be738d8bae32ec21d86/examples/saga-counter/src/main.js

Comment: `const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(         window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f,
    applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware)
  ));`

Comment: It is not working? :-) I can only get it to work if my dev tools are first and saga after.

Comment: Woops, i mean sagas first and dev tools after!

Answer (score 0):

I think the wait function is wrong type.
you have to fix like this.

```
const wait = ms => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {  
    setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms)  
  })
}
```